# Control Mediaplayer from another Activity

Tags: android

I have 2 activity: Main and Setting

In MainActivity, I have a public static Mediaplayer mp to start background music for my application

Now, I am in SettingActivity, i have a Switch to turn background music on or off

```
public void listenSwitch()
{
    s.setChecked(true); // On

    s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked == false)
            {
                MainActivity.mp.stop(); // Works
            }
            else
            {
               // I use create(this, raw file) and then MainActivity.mp.start(); but error occurs
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I can turn background music off but i can not turn it on

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) you see that MediaPlayer.stop() requires you to prepare() the player again before next start().

> Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started,
>   Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped
>   state. Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until
>   prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object
>   to the Prepared state again.

Maybe you want to do a pause() because it seems that it doesn't need a new prepare() or prepareAsync().

Good luck!

Comment: great! thank you too much.

I just need to pause(), its much more easier